# Software Design Mutator Changing a Different Field-Design Question

Tags: java, oop

This is in Java, but should be language indepedent.

Supposed I have a class

```
public class RentableRoom {
int price;
int temp;
............
public void setTemp(int temp){
       this.temp = temp;
       updateRentalPrice();

    }
    public double calculateRentalPrice(double basePrice){
        double tempPrice = basePrice;

        if (getTemp() >= 20 && getTemp() <= 40){
            tempPrice += 50.0;
        }
        return tempPrice;  
    }
    public void updateRentalPrice(){
        double tempPrice = calculateRentalPrice(getBasePrice());
        setRentalPrice(tempPrice);
    }

}
```

If the room's temperature level is set between 20 and 40, then there is a surcharge of 50 dollars. So I can't change temperature without potentially having to mutate another field, price. Is that bad design to have a mutator for a field, but then potentilly change another field.  I really don't see a way out of it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bad thing. And the best way to do this is to not set price at all but reflect this in a getter method. In your case

```
public double calculateRentalPrice(double basePrice){

    return price + (getTemp() >= 20 && getTemp() <= 40) ? 50 : 0;
}
```

And just use that for getting the rental price. Don't change your member variables

Comment: Can I have a gettinger method that calls the updateValue() just before returning the value?  Is this what you have in mind?